# Here Document to interact with VI

Tags: bash, shell, vim, vi, heredoc

I was just trying to figure out EOF and here documents. I read something online that seemed like a cool idea I could expand upon. It is supposed to create a text file, and add text to it, all using a here document. The syntax is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
filename=test.txt
vim $filename <<EndOfCommands
i
This file was created automatically from
a shell script.
^[
ZZ
EndOfCommands
```

Now unfortunately I get an error from this:

```
./EOF.sh 
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...

Vim: Finished.
```

Can anyone help fix this error? Also im assuming ^[ stands for the escape button being hit?

Comment: Use `sed` to have a scriptable text editor that is exactly here for your purpose.

Comment: Use `ex`, not `vim`. It's the non-visual version. Or good old `ed`.

Comment: c.f. the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ex) for useful details.

Comment: Replace `$filename` with `-` to read from stdin.

Answer (score 2):

`vi` and `vim` are meant to be used interactively in a terminal, not scripted.

Using `ed` instead, which can happily accept input from standard input sources of all types:

```
#!/bin/sh
filename=test.txt
ed -s "$filename" <<EndOfCommands
i
This file was created automatically from
a shell script.
.
w
EndOfCommands
```

(In insert mode, a line with a single period indicates end-of-input and goes back to command mode, kind of like escape in `vi(m)`.)

Using `ex` is another option; on systems with `vim` installed it's often a non-**v**isual version of it.

Answer (score 2):

With vim:

```
filename="test.txt"
vim -c ":wq! $filename" - << EOF
This file was created automatically from
a shell script.
EOF
```

---

See: `man vim`